# ArtemisMQ Address Memory Filling Up Too Quickly

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am using ArtemisMQ 2.17. When I look at each of the Queues, the message count for each always shows 0 as we have listeners actively scanning to pick up messages quickly. However, when I look at the overall message count on the broker, it starts to grow from 0 to upwards of millions; this starts to grow about 20 minutes into running the broker.

If I restart the broker service, my address memory is cleared. Sometimes, which I haven't determined the time interval just yet, when I restart the service, I'll see messages show up in the ExpiryQueue. But this doesn't happen everytime I restart the service; only sometimes.

Our application is using Spring JMS for the Producer and Listeners; The addresses/queues are multicast.

Here is what I am seeing on the broker attributes section in the console. I would expect message count to always be 0 but after 20min or so, it starts to climb indefinitely, and the acknowledged and added start to not match up at that point.

[image]

What can I do so that messages are picked up and completely removed? OR What's happening here? Where are these messages going and why do they randomly appear in my ExpiryQueue after a few restarts?

Output of: ./artemis queue stat
[image]

View in console for broker level attributes:
[image]

Comment: That's the thing; I can look at the queues in the web console and each queue always says 0 message count; which is what I expect with having listeners. But when I look at the attributes on the broker itself, I see Total Message Count go from 0 to many after 20min of the broker being online. I'm wondering if I should get rid of the ExpiryQueue and set a timeToLive for the message; but not sure of the implications.

Comment: pasted screenshot of output in description. I'm just curious why address memory is filling up if messages are being picked up from the queue as expected. And when I look at the broker attributes, the message on queue count is very high and doesn't match acknowledge. Wondering where these messages are and what I can do to prevent them from going to "The Void " and taking up address memory. I have to restart the broker about every 3-5 days because 2GB of memory is taken up in that time span; where I wouldn't expect us to need that if messages are only needed for a short life span

Comment: Messages will eventually show up in the expiryQueue but it takes days; and it's only about 10K at a time; where message count in 1 day can get upwards of 3 million in 1-2 days.

Comment: I would have expected to see more queues from the `queue stat` command. `ExpiryQueue` isn't even showing up on that which is odd. On the same screen where you're inspecting "Total message count" can you paste the value of "Queue count", "Queue names", "Address Count", and "Address Names"?

Comment: @JustinBertram - So looking a little more closely, I am seeing that activemq.notifications has millions of un routed messages because there is no queue for it. I created a queue and messages are pouring into it. So now I'm going to test deleting this address completely.

Comment: Messages which are "unrouted" do not accumulate anywhere and would not be reflected in the "Total message count" since they do not reside in any queues. The notifications address is an internal address and really shouldn't be deleted. If you create a queue on it then you'll almost certainly have a problem since nothing will be consuming those messages. I recommend you just leave it as is and keep investigating to find the real cause of the message accumulation.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted?